# iOS. Build errors when subclassing or adding a category on a class?

Tags: ios, build, subclass, categories, game-center

I have added the following code into my project:

[link](https://github.com/typeoneerror/GKAchievementNotification)

These classes are for game center in iOS and they allow to compile a project if I simply use them. But when I try to subclass it or create a category for it then it shows a lot of errors about GKAchievementDescription. And it occurs even if I had created a subclass or category only but didn't use them.

Why doesn't it work properly and is it possible to solve this problem without of editing the classes from this library?

**UPDATED**

Here is an example of using this class:

```
#import "GKAchievementHandler.h"

@interface GKAchievementHandler (Extension)

@end

#import "GKAchievementHandler+Extension.h"

@implementation GKAchievementHandler (Extension)

@end
```

The code from the library before isn't used in my project anywhere else. Example of error text:

> /GKAchievementNotification-master/GKAchievementNotification.h:68:5:
>   Unknown type name 'GKAchievementDescription'; did you mean
>   'GKAchievementNotification'?

Comment: show the code where you import the 3rd party classes and try to use them.

Comment: here is a code. Hope this will help

Comment: have you imported game kit ?

Comment: thanks. Now it works. Can you post this as an answer? But I still can't understand why had it worked before I created a category/subclass for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `GameKit` framework.

The following is a wooly description of a difficult topic to describe with abuse of many terms...

Previously it wasn't required because you were just using the framework via the library and it was already compiled with references. So you were using 'weak' references for anything you were doing.

Now that you're actually subclassing, you're really trying to use the classes so you need a full 'strong' definition with which to compile your modifications.

It's the same as the difference between:

```
@class XXX;
```

and:

```
#import XXX.h;
```

and what they each allow you to do with `XXX`.